# Add reference .NET Framework project to .NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a question about possibilities to add .NET Framework Project to .NET Core project. At my solution, I have main application in .NET Core and i want to extand it by existig own .NET Framework project. I don't have for now any idea how to do this, but I need it. Now i do WCF with which I connect from Core project, but better for my is added to Core by reference. If I add project by reference, I get exception...

Anyone can help me?
Thanks

@edit

> Could not load file or assembly 'App.Dynamic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. An attempt was made to load the program in an incorrect format.

.NET Framework 4
.NET Core 2.1

Comment: What error message do you get? What libraries does the .NET Framework use? .NET Core does not support all of .NET Framework, it won't work magically

Comment: Take a look at this blog post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceAnExistingNETFrameworkProjectInAnASPNETCore10WebApp.aspx

Comment: > Could not load file or assembly 'App.Dynamic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. An attempt was made to load the program in an incorrect format.

.NET Framework 4
.NET Core 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having a 32-bit / 64-bit conflict. You are somehow missing "platform target" dropdown in `project-->properties-->build`. Value should be same for both the projects.

Comment: My project in .NET Core is https://aspnetboilerplate.com. My own project must have 32 bit, because they use another reference which i can't change to 64 bit. When I downgrade other projects from ASP .NET Boilerplate to 32 bit, project don't build and start. I don't know what to do...